# Amazon EC2: instace in public subnetwork without public IP vs instance in private subnetwork

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC created according to scenario 2: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario2.html

When creating an instance in the public subnet, I'm given the choice of:

1- Not associating a public IP to the instance

2- Associating a public IP that can change when the instance is restarted

3- Associating an Elastic IP

My question is: what is the difference, security-wise, between creating an instance in the public subnet but without a public IP (option 1) and creating the instance in the private subnet? I know that private instances are behind a NAT, but does this really add a relevant layer of security? Wouldn't I be as protected with a public instance without a public IP belonging to a sound security group?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out this [answer about the difference between private and public subnets in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188444/why-do-we-need-private-subnet-in-vpc).

In short, the distinction is at the networking layer with the resulting security posture being similar. The instance on the public subnet without a publicly routable address will not be able to receive inbound connections nor make outbound connections without an attached EIP address -- even if the security group would otherwise allow it. (So, for example, you'd have to attach an EIP just to SSH into the instance.) In effect, it's a blanket block whereas the NAT allows you to fine tune access like you would normally expect.

You can also read more about [instance addressing in the AWS User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html).