# How to make HTTP call reaching all instances behind App Engine load balancer?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to make HTTP call to all instances running behind an google app engine load balancer.

This is a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498423/how-to-make-a-http-call-reaching-all-instances-behind-amazon-aws-load-balancer) for aws.

Comment: Stackoverflow is ignoring aws link I provided above - so here is AWS question link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498423/how-to-make-a-http-call-reaching-all-instances-behind-amazon-aws-load-balancer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the standard environment and manual scaling (not possible for auto/basic scaling) you could use [Targeted routing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#targeted_routing) to reach a particular instance:

> ```
> https://[INSTANCE_ID]-dot-[VERSION_ID]-dot-[SERVICE_ID]-dot-[MY_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com
> http://[INSTANCE_ID].[VERSION_ID].[SERVICE_ID].[MY_CUSTOM_DOMAIN]
> ```
>
> **Note:** Targeting an instance is not supported in services that are configured for auto scaling or basic scaling. The instance ID must be
>   an integer in the range from 0, up to the total number of instances
>   running. Regardless of your scaling type or instance class, it is not
>   possible to send a request to a specific instance without targeting a
>   service or version within that instance.

If you're using the flexible environment it's not possible to reach a specific instance. From [Targeted routing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-requests-are-routed#targeted_routing):

> **Note:** In the flexible environment, targeting an instance is not supported. It is not possible to send requests directly to a specific
>   instance.