# Are Amazon Lightsail instances managed / automatically updated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, vps, amazon-lightsail

I have been looking into Amazon Lightsail, but there is one thing that I haven't been able to find any information on.

Are instances managed and updated automatically? In particular, I thinking of OS / web server security updates.

With EC2, I have to log in every now and then to perform OS upgrades, updates and install security patches. This is fine for EC2, but I am now looking to set up a VPS that I can essentially install and forget, system-wise at least.

Apologies if this is on the wrong site, but there is an [amazon-lightsail](/questions/tagged/amazon-lightsail) tag here after all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, they are not managed. You deal with Amazon Lightsail instances the same as you do with EC2 instances in terms of OS updates.

For a more detailed answer on the difference between EC2 and Lightsail instances, you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40932906/3770040) by @**Michael - sqlbot**.