# Frozen trying to install Hyperledger composer-rest-server on AWS Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-composer, amazon-lightsail

I tried to install Hyperledger Composer on my AWS Lightsail following instructions documented on https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html

I succeeded until step 3, where I entered `npm install -g composer-rest-server`.  It complains about several deprecated items and on the 5th times, it just got frozen. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOTaD.png)

Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: What's the spec of the machine  and what are you trying to run concurrently in this machine ? Maybe you don't have enough memory ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  According to AWS, Lightsail has 512MB memory, 1vCPU, 20GB SSD and 1TB data transfer (more detailed analysis on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927189/what-is-difference-between-lightsail-and-ec2).

Comment: I too suspect the Lightsail is too "weak" but how can I check if the problem is memory related?   Is there anything I can do (other than using a more powerful VPS?)?

Comment: I am not running anything else on this instance / VPS other than Fabric and Composer files from Hyperledger.

Comment: we recommend a memory footprint of at least 3.75Gb, so I suspect its failing to build the Fabric environment as part of the composer install (tutorial includes standing up a Dev Fabric environment). Ps what OS distro did you use for the Lightsail service in the end?

Answer (score 0):

we recommend a memory footprint of at least 3.75Gb, so I suspect its failing to build the Fabric environment as part of the composer install (tutorial includes standing up a Dev Fabric environment).

Comment: Thank you.  Memory is probably a critical success factor.  Will try to use another server with more memory.  Incidentally, can the various "deprecated" warnings signs of other problems?

Comment: not really (where Composer is concerned) - these are 'standard' nodejs messages seen during the install.  This warning is displayed because one of your direct dependency is out of date or one the npm packages in the dependency tree.  This article will help explain -> https://www.triplet.fi/blog/how_node_package_deprecation_works/