# Are AWS Lightsail databases subject to burst performance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

Given [What is difference between Lightsail and EC2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927189/what-is-difference-between-lightsail-and-ec2) and my own testing, I am convinced that LightSail  Instances are [burstable performance instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html).

1. Are [LightSail **database** instances](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-managed-databases-for-amazon-lightsail/) subject to this kind of burstable performance too? I'm interested in both I/O burst and CPU burst.
2. If so, is there a way to view the remaining CPU or IO burst credits? Unlike EC2, the web console for LightSail doesn't seem to offer these numbers.

Comment: 3 years later was it ever determined if the Lightsail RDS instances are subject to burst performance, or will they run the same.

Answer (score 0):

This issue hit me hard today, taking down my instances making them unable to serve any request

Just want to inform you that they include the bursts area into their metric now. But I dont see the way to get remaining credits

[Also now the burstable "feature" is documented](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/faq/)

[image]