# Is AWS lightsail IaaS or PaaS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

AWS lightsail works similarly to EC2, which is Iaas service. But this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535482/aws-vs-lightsail-what-is-the-difference) answered its a Paas service which confuse me. So is lightsail Iaas or Paas?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes definitions like IaaS and PaaS get bit blurry.

It is pretty clear that Amazon EC2 is IaaS. By contrast then Amazon Lighsail looks more PaaS.  From [the docs](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/what-is-amazon-lightsail)

> Amazon Lightsail is the easiest way to get started with Amazon Web Services (AWS) for developers who need to build websites or web applications. It includes everything you need to launch your project quickly - instances (virtual private servers), container services, managed databases, content delivery network (CDN) distributions, load balancers, SSD-based block storage, static IP addresses, DNS management of registered domains, and resource snapshots (backups) - for a low, predictable monthly price.

Comparing EC2 and Lightsail, the accepted answer here may also be helpful to you: [What is difference between Lightsail and EC2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927189/what-is-difference-between-lightsail-and-ec2)