# Why do we need AWS VPC NAT instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

AWS beginner here. This question is about AWS VPC NAT instances.

As per the docs "You can use a network address translation (NAT) instance in a public subnet in your VPC to enable instances in the private subnet to initiate outbound IPv4 traffic to the Internet or other AWS services, but prevent the instances from receiving inbound traffic initiated by someone on the Internet."

But can this not be achieved by using a security group with the outbound rule: "0.0.0.0/0: All traffic" and restricting the inbound rule to receive only from within the VPC?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Sure it can. Its about fine grain security setup.

Comment: I can allow a co-worker to spin up the machines only in the private subnet and then I don't have to worry if they got the SG right.

Comment: I recommend asking this question on https://security.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: See also [Why do we need private subnets in VPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22212017/1695906)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But can this not be achieved by using a security group with outbound
>   rule : "0.0.0.0/0: All traffic" and restricting the inbound rule to
>   receive only from within the VPC?

The above is true only if the instances also have a public IP address assigned to them. If they do not have a public IP assigned to them then the NAT gateway/instance is required for Internet access.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I do assign public IPs and restrict inbound traffic using a security group, am I in effect achieving the same thing as a NAT? I do understand that this may not be the right design, but just want to know if that is correct.

Comment: You are achieving the goal to restrict traffic to outbound only. A NAT instance can provide additional things, for example logging of all outbound traffic, so the two methods aren't exactly "the same thing". Also, if you are using AWS Lambda functions that need to be in your VPC, then you can't assign public IPs to those, so a NAT is the only option to provide VPC Lambda functions with Internet access.

Comment: @Aravind For devices inside a VPC to connect to devices outside the VPC, it needs one of the following: IGW (Internet Gateway), NAT Gateway, VGW, VPC EndPoint. Each type of device / connectivity option has its own features and benefits. Security Groups complement these connectivity options but do not replace them.