# How lambda connects to s3 inside vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I can't distinguish between privite subnet and public subnet.

I created a vpc and connected the subnet, and igw was also connected to the route tables. So, isn't the network a public subnet?

As I expected, the public network seems to have to communicate with the outside, but there is no communication at all.

Connection from aws lambda to RDS is possible (vpc), but timeout occurs for both uploading files to s3 and sending messages to slack.

I have seen a lot of posts about using vpc endpoints, but when I try to set it up

> Warning
>
> When you use an endpoint, the source IP addresses from your
> instances in your affected subnets for accessing the AWS service in
> the same region will be private IP addresses, not public IP addresses.
> Existing connections from your affected subnets to the AWS service
> that use public IP addresses may be dropped. Ensure that you do n’t
> have critical tasks running when you create or modify an endpoint.

So isn't ec2 currently disconnected from s3? Then, there is a problem with the service and it cannot be set.

In the lambda vpc configuration, even if all inbounds of the security group are opened, the connection is not established.

Is there only a way to set up NAT?

NAT wants to avoid it because of its cost.

my goal is to communicate with rds, s3, slack in lambda on vpc.

Comment: Your lambda is in private or public subnet?

Comment: @Marcin My lambda is set to vpc. In my expectation, it should be a public subnet, but it is probably not a public subnet, so I can't communicate with the outside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can identify a public subnet vs. a private subnet because a public subnet in AWS is a subnet whose route table has a default route to an Internet Gateway (IGW).

The IGW logically provides 1:1 NAT on behalf of an AWS network interface (e.g. on an EC2 instance) if that network interface has a public IPv4 address. It does not, however, perform NAT for private IPs so if your network interface (on an EC2 instance or Lambda function or other) does not have a public IP then that traffic will be dropped at the IGW.

How do Lambda functions that you deploy into your VPC reach the internet (for example, to talk to Slack or S3)? They have to route through a NAT. Typically, you deploy them into a private subnet and that subnet's route table has a default route to a NAT device or NAT gateway in a public subnet, and the VPC has a configured IGW.

Why can't a Lambda function deployed into a public subnet reach the internet? Because the public subnet's default route is the IGW, the Lambda function does not have a public IP, and the IGW drops all traffic from private IPs.

How can a Lambda function reach S3 without also allowing it to reach the internet? You deploy the Lambda function into a VPC private subnet and you configure an S3 VPC endpoint in the VPC. Now the Lambda can reach S3 privately.

How can a Lambda function reach an RDS database, which itself is in a private subnet? You deploy the Lambda function into a private subnet, you configure the Lambda with a Security Group, and you configure the RDS instance security group to allow inbound traffic from the Lambda security group.

How do Lambda functions that are *not* deployed into VPC reach the internet? Lambda functions do not, and cannot, have public IPs so they must route through a NAT somehow. But you didn't deploy a VPC never mind a NAT so how does it work? The Lambda function has a network interface (an ENI) that *is* actually deployed into a VPC, but it's not *your* VPC. It's an AWS-managed VPC and that VPC has a NAT Gateway.

OK, back to your situation. You want your Lambda function to reach Slack (over the internet), S3 (any way possible), and RDS (which is in your VPC's private subnet). That's a challenging combination because, while we could reach both RDS and S3 privately (via intrinsic VPC routing to RDS and by VPC endpoint to S3), we can't reach Slack that way. Or we could reach both S3 and Slack if we deployed outside of VPC (via a NAT in the AWS-managed VPC) but then we could not access private RDS.

So, I think you need to deploy the Lambda into a private subnet, that subnet needs a default route to a NAT Gateway in a public subnet, you need an IGW, and you need to correctly configure security groups on your Lambda function and RDS instance to allow inbound access from the Lambda to RDS. S3 traffic will route publicly. Or you could add an S3 VPC endpoint, if you need to keep the S3 traffic private.

More helpful useful info here:

- [mixing VPC and non-VPC Lambda functions](https://www.jeremydaly.com/mixing-vpc-and-non-vpc-lambda-functions-for-higher-performing-microservices/)
- [why do we need private subnets in VPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188444/why-do-we-need-private-subnet-in-vpc)

PS if there's any chance that you have messed up your VPC, while modifying route tables or other means, then I suggest deleting that VPC and using the AWS console VPC wizard to create a new one.

Comment: Thank you.
I will also read the post you gave me and rebuild the vpc. If it doesn't continue, I will leave a comment again.

Comment: May I ask you one more?
What are the warnings when setting up a vpc endpoint? I don't understand

Comment: It’s warning you about potential disconnects if you have existing connections to S3.  Any connected instances are going to switch from connecting from a public IP to S3 to a private IP to S3 via private endpoint. If you don’t have any running instances or active connections then it’s irrelevant. That’s my understanding, anyhow.

Comment: Is there any way to see all the connections connected to s3?

Now I log the log as s3 in ec2 and lambda, but I don't think it will continue to be connected.

Comment: Ideally all of this infrastructure is built first, using CloudFormation or equivalent, before your app is in service. If you’re applying this change to existing infrastructure then you have a general problem to solve of quiescing existing connections that’s not trivial to solve. You’d need some programmatic way to tell all your instances to pause any S3 interaction. Or you build in some resilience to your apps, so they can handle disconnect and will reconnect and retry.